# Why is the jquery multi upload plugin not uploading?

Tags: php, jquery, upload, file-upload, multifile-uploader

I am using the multi-upload plugin found at: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/

This is what I am doing:

These steps will reproduce the problem:

1. Create a file input field, add 'multi-upload' as the class and 'images[]' as the name
2. Use the input field to select an image and redirect to upload.php page via the action parameter on the form field
3. I tried to echo out the images array on the upload.php page using echo $_FILES['images[0]']['size']; but nothing appears so the image(s) never uploads.
4. If I remove the 'multi-upload' class from the input field, it works fine and using the echo i mentioned in #3, echoes out the size of the uploaded image.

What version of the plugin/jQuery am I using?
JQUERY VERSION: I am using v.1.4.6

On what browser(s) or operating system?
BROWSER(S): windows xp, windows vista

Please provide a link to where the problem can be observed:
URL: http://www.idea-palette.com/port/vacation_showcase/admin/mailinglist/index.php?action=create-mail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the answer you are looking for, just a suggestion.

I would give you an suggestion to use an other upload plugin instead of this.

I've used this myself and I really like it. It's easy to use and requires almost no code to implement.

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/)